# execute list of queries in a single shot in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to build a setup file, .exe, which contains a web-application, required softwares and also required tables in the database... so, to make tht .exe we need to run the list of queries. is there any solution for it?

Comment: yes there is a solution. But what is your specific question?

Comment: I need to run a query list which contains all the create table queries. the database  I m using is PostgreSQL 8.2

Comment: query list would be a text file or an sql file containing all the queries

Answer (score 1):

It's called a transaction, and is covered [in the introductory tutorial in the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html).

You `BEGIN` a transaction, run your sequence of commands, and `COMMIT` the transaction. You can wrap it all up in a script and feed it into `psql`.

Please don't bundle the PostgreSQL installer and run it as a silent install, by the way. Either ask the user to run it (so they know the `postgres` admin password etc) or bundle the plain binaries and run `initdb` and `pg_ctl` yourself in your app.

Comment: Could you please explain how the transaction works through a code snippet, so that I could understand it well ??

Comment: @Deepali There's a great deal of information out there on the basics of transactions, including the PostgreSQL tutorial. Start there. If the link above doesn't make sense to you yet, start at the beginning of the tutorial: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html

Comment: I read the tutorial, but, how to get it done through java coding?

Comment: @Deepali PgJDBC supports sending multiple statements in a single `execute()`, but for Java I'd generally recommend keeping your database setup code in an XML file or similar, something you can read and execute statement-by-statement. In Java you just turn off autocommit to start a transaction then do an explicit commit. Read the JDBC tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/